# How to setup data structure for real estate app in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to build a MVP for a real estate system using React and Firebase. I have used SQL databases in the past and hence find it difficult to understand the NoSQL concepts (collections, documents, fields).

Below are the tables I would set up in an SQL database and wanted to know how to set up the fields in Firebase. The front end client should not download irrelevant documents and we should be able to query documents across collections.

For example: What's the property address of a particular household member.

**Property**

- PropCode
- Start Date
- End Date
- Property Type - (House, Unit, Villa)
- Property Source - ( Developer, Housing, Self)
- Address ( State, Post Code\Zip Code, Suburb, Street)

**Tenancy**

- TenancyID
- PropCode - Links to the property table
- Tenancy Start Date
- Tenancy End Date
- Tenancy Type (LongTerm, Short Term)

**Household**

- HHID - The household ID
- HHMID - The household member ID. Each member in the household is assigned an ID
- FirstName
- LastName
- DOB
- Email
- HHM Start Date
- HHM End Date

**Household-Tenancy** - Table to link household with Tenancy

- TenancyID
- HHID

Thanks
Jag

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is really having a vast scope and it cannot be entirely covered in one answer.

Here is my try to give you a starting point:

**Note:** This is for Firebase Firestore (*not Realtime Database*).

## Firebase Firestore Schema (Brief):

In firebase, you have a *collection* which simply can be said as a bunch of **documents**. Now, what are documents? Documents are the actual place where your data reside. So for eg., you will have a collection named *users* which would have all the users' documents (data).

Refer here for more details: [Firebase Firestore Model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

## Your Answer (a try):

---

### Collection-Properties:

which would contain all of the properties' documents. Each document would contain data of the property (*address, unit etc..*). It would also contain the type of the Property (*room, house etc.)* and the **UID** (*the unique ID of a user in Firebase*) of the current tenant (*By this you can query for the user using his **UID** in the *Tenants* collection*). The document would also contain a subcollection- *Previous Tenants* which would contain the documents with details of the previous tenants.
  
This would also contain all the demographic details of the properties, (a subcollection is recommended not a separate collection).

**NOTE: Firestore document can contain at maximum 1mib, so if there is possibility of exceeding that limit then you can break down the details into subcollections.**

---

### Collection- Tenants:

which would contain all the tenants' documents. Each document would contain data of the tenant (*name, rent etc*) and the **document ID** of the property in which he is currently living (*By which you can query the property*). Also, it would contain a subcollection-*Previous Properties* which would have the details of the previous properties in which he lived.

I'm not quite sure about what you mean by rent statement but if it just means the total rent the tenant has to pay in a week, you can directly have a subcollection which would contain the tenant's weekly rent.

---

I hope I was able to cover you listed assets. In these cases, no one can say a **correct** or a **wrong** data structure. You just need to think of the one, which suits you best.

Additional Bonus: [Advanced Data Modeling with Firestore by Example](https://fireship.io/lessons/advanced-firestore-nosql-data-structure-examples/)

Comment: "it cannot be entirely covered in one answer" then it means it should be closed instead. Please do not answer questions that cannot be answered.

Comment: Hi Sommyee, I have update the question and if you could help how to structure the fields in firebase pls.

Comment: You just need to do have a link between all of the assets which can be the **Document ID** of the other asset. For eg. to get the property address of a particular person, you retrieve the property's document ID stored in the person's document. And then just query it in the properties collection from which you can get the address of the property.  There is nothing more, I can do. I gave the answer to give you a starting point, now after having that starting point you need to work upon it.